# learning java/spring from python/django

Tags: java, django, spring

I am required to pick up java (with basic previous experiences) + 1 specific application framework, having spending most of my times in Python and Django. Chose Spring mainly due to my requirements.

May I know what could be the equivalent of Django's development server in Java so I can easily run and check my Java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy a web app using Spring to any Java EE app server.  I'd say that the simplest choice would be Tomcat, the Apache servlet/JSP engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) which is a lightweight servlet container like Tomcat, but keep in mind the problems regarding deployment of Java EE applications mentioned in this thread [Can Jetty be used as a Java EE lightweight application server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903823/can-jetty-be-used-as-a-java-ee-lightweight-application-server).

Another alternative is [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/index.html) then Glassfish is a good fit since there is very good integration between the two.